# Как проверить что все элементы массива пустые?

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив:

```
$error = ['url' => null, 'title' => null, 'icon' => null, 'color' => null];
```

С его помощью я проверяю форму, и если есть ошибки, я в соответствующий элемент массива записываю строку с текстом ошибки.

Например:

Если поле `url` пустое, тогда массив будет выглядеть так:

```
Array
    (
        [url] => Это поле обязательно к заполнению
        [title] => 
        [icon] => 
        [color] => 
    )
```

Сейчас я проверяю так:

```
if (empty($error['url']) and empty($error['title']) and empty($error['icon']) and empty($error['color'])) {

    'Отправляю форму'

}
```

Как проверить, что все элементы массива пустые более лучшим способом?
Может есть стандартная функция, которая проверяет на пустоту все элементы массива?

Answer (score 2):

```
$error = ['url' => null, 'title' => "2", 'icon' => null, 'color' => null];
print_r(array_diff($error, array(''))); // Если возвращается пустой массив, значит нет значений. В противном случае вернёт то, которое не пустое.
```

```php
<?php
$error = ['url' => null, 'title' => "2", 'icon' => null, 'color' => null];

$Empty = ""; // Переменная со значением для вывода
foreach ($error as $key=>$value){ // проверяем массив
    if ($value){
        $Empty = 'есть не пустые значения';
        break;
    } else {
        $Empty = 'Все значения пустые';
    }
}

print_r($Empty); // Выводим сообщение
```

Comment: Может быть есть стандартная функция для проверки?

Comment: @Verstala можно воспользоваться таким методом `print_r(array_diff($error, array('')));` Добавил комментарии к методу

Answer (score 2):

```
$array = ['url' => null, 'title' => null, 'icon' => null, 'color' => null];

if (empty(array_filter(array_values($array)))) {
    // не заполнено 1 и более полей
}
```

Comment: просто `!array_filter($data)` хватить ведь должно, зачем усложнять?

Answer (score 1):

```
$error = [
    'url' => null,
    'title' => 'Это поле ...',
    'icon' => null, 
    'color' => 'Это поле ...'
];
$e = [];

foreach ($error as $k => $v) {
    if ($v) {
        array_push($e, $k);
    }
}
```

Или проще:

```
$e = array_keys($error, !null);
```

Если все элементы `$error` пустые, массив `$e` останется пустым, иначе будет содержать значения ключей c непустыми значениями `$error`

```
// print_r($e);
Array
(
    [0] => title
    [1] => color
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать через [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php) (возвращает все найденные сравнения)

```
<?php

$error = ['url' => null, 'title' => "2", 'icon' => 2, 'color' => null];

$filter = array_filter($error, function($item) {
    return $item === null;
});

if (empty($filter))
    echo "Все поля заполнены";
else
    foreach($filter as $key => $value) {
        echo "Поле '{$key}' не заполнено" . PHP_EOL;
    }
```

Можно через [`array_search`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-search.php) (возвращает первый найденный элемент)

```
<?php

$error = ['url' => null, 'title' => "2", 'icon' => 2, 'color' => null];

$search = array_search(null, $error);

if ($search)
    echo "Поле '{$search}' не заполнено";
```

Можно через [`in_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.in-array.php) (возвращает `bool`)

```
<?php

$error = ['url' => null, 'title' => "2", 'icon' => 2, 'color' => null];

$inArray = in_array(null, $error);

if ($inArray === true)
    echo "Не все поля заполнены";
```